# Migration of records to the table with different column names

Tags: mysql, migration

I have two databases, and I need to move data from one to another. The catch is they have a table with different set of columns. Here is how I need to rename columns in migration:

```
NULL -> ID (should be generated as I add records normally)
NULL -> category_id (should be fixed, e.g. 3)
date_art -> created_at
title_art -> title
short_art -> promo
full_art -> content
```

Is it possible to accomplish by a single query?

Comment: Is the `ID` column an `autoincrement` column?

Comment: Yes. It should be an autoincrement column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL would be like:

```
insert into tab1 (category_id, created_at, title, promo, content)
as
select 3, date_art, title_art, short_art, full_art
from   tab2
```

The `ID` column will get it's value during the insert.